# perl - can't get data using m//g string

Tags: perl

i'm using this but i don't get anything

```
    my $maldet = "https://myanimelist.net/anime/35849/Darling_in_the_FranXX";
my $response = $ua->request(HTTP::Request->new(GET => $maldet));
my $rrs = $response->content;
while ($rrs =~ m/<span itemprop=\"name\">(.*?)<\/span>/g) {
my $ANIME_NAME = $1;
print item("ANIME NAME"),("$ANIME_NAME\n");
}
```

this original source code , and i want to get DATA

```
<span itemprop="name">DATA</span>
```

please help , what i need to edit in my script

Comment: Are you sure it's a web service? It doesn't look like one

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions. Also, you can shorten your LWP code to `$ua->get($url)`, no need to create your own HTTP::Request object if you don't do anything special with it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include sample input. Tell us what's in `$ANIME_LINK` so we get to see the real website.

Comment: ah its like : https://myanimelist.net/anime/35849/Darling_in_the_FranXX

Comment: If you want to process all matches in that loop you might consider adding the `c` flag to your regular expression. And, as some of these `<span itemprop="name">...</span>` span multiple lines, the `s` flag might also be useful to match these. (These flags go to the end: `m/<span itemprop=\"name\">(.*?)<\/span>/gcs`)

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favor and [don't parse HTML with regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). While there are several modules to parse HTML properly in Perl (e.g. [`HTML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Parser) and [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) are two classics), [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) has a nice interface and can be used together with [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $LINK = "test.html";
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $dom = $ua->get("https://www.example.com/$LINK")->result->dom;
$dom->find(q{ span[itemprop="name"] })->each(sub {
        my $text = $_->text;
        print "<$text>\n";
    });
```

Comment: so to parse html its more simple to use Mojo::UserAgent

Comment: Yes, [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) is a pretty good HTML parser. The `->dom` method is returning a `Mojo::DOM` object, but you can parse HTML strings and files by using `Mojo::DOM` directly (its docs show you how).